# How to show exception status code on error page use springmvc

Tags: spring-mvc

Custom exception

```
public class JsonException extends RuntimeException{

private int code;

public JsonException() {
}

public JsonException(String message) {
    super(message);
}
public JsonException(int code, String message) {
    super(message);
    this.code = code;
}

public JsonException(Throwable cause) {
    super(cause);
}

public JsonException(String message, Throwable cause) {
    super(message, cause);
}
```

}

Rest URI

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class Rests {


@GetMapping("/e")
public Boolean exceptionCode() {
    throw new JsonException(401, "test");
}}
```

Request for '/api/e', the error page write status 500.The problem is how to make the message is 'status=401,Type =test',

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are directly throwing exception in controller that why you got internal server error.

If you want return any specific reason then you have to construct object need to set the reason by exception.getMessage() and set the status code.

Comment: My question is why it will display 500 when a custom exception is thrown, can I customize it?

Comment: In your controller return type boolean then all successful scenario it will return true or false not your exception. If you want display any customized things then you have change the return type.

Comment: emmmm，I mean how to display it on the error page。

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-error-page
Follow above tutorial.

Comment: Maybe i need to use 
` response.sendError(401);`.

Comment: I think so that tutorial will help you.